# How to create an executable that can run on both 32bit and 64bit for Linux? Is it related to the format as SYSV and GNU / Linux?

Tags: linux, gnu

I am a beginner in programming. I want to create an executable that can run on both 32bit and 64bit for Linux. I am using a Linux operating system version.

I found the file "xampp-linux-5.6.20-0-installer.run" listed as:

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU / Linux),
>   statically linked, stripped

(Checked with `file` in Terminal)
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: 32-bit (x86) executables do run both on 32-bit (x86) and 64-bit (x86_64) CPUs as 64-bit ones are backwards compatible.

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Linking with 32bit libraries under linux 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605384/linking-with-32bit-libraries-under-linux-64bit)

Comment: Thanjs to David!

Answer (score 2):

32 bit application can run on both 32 and 64 bit machines. You will have to install some 32 bit packages on 64 bit. Detail steps are here: [Run 32-bit application on 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

Comment: It is generally better to link to a StackOverflow answer if one is readily available, e.g. [Linking with 32bit libraries under linux 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605384/linking-with-32bit-libraries-under-linux-64bit) -- simply looking at the Right-Column under **Related** links is a good place to start. But good effort for providing a link to begin with.